# Show for any prime $p$ and $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p}$ that $x^p-a$ has multiple roots

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, solution-verification

Show for any prime $p$ and $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p}$ that $x^p-a$ has multiple roots

using the derivative of $x^p-a$ which is $px^{p-1}$ if they are relatively prime then $x^p-a$ only has simple roots.

in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$,     $\,\,px^{p-1}=0$ and so $x^p-a \mid x^p-a$
 and $x^p - a \mid px^{p-1} = 0$ thus GCD$(x^p-a, px^{p-1}) = x^p-a$ so $x^p-a$ has multiple roots

Comment: What do you mean with $\mathbb F_p$?

Comment: @k1.M it is alternative notiation for $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @k1.M This is a common notation for the field with $p$ elements.

Comment: As a less elegant alternative, note that if $p$ is an odd prime, then the root $a$ has multiplicity $p$. In other words, then $x^p-a$ factors in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ as $(x-a)^p$, which can be proved using the fact that $a^p=a \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and that $p$ divides $\binom{p}{k}$ for all $1 \leq k \leq p-1$. You can check it for small values of $a$ and $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb Z_3[x]$ the polynomial $x^6+1$ has formal derivative equal to zero, however does not have any zeroes (so any multiple zeroes) in $\mathbb Z_3$.

> Let $\mathbb F$ be a field. A polynomial $f\in\mathbb F[x]$ has a multiple root, if and only if, the polynomial $g=(f,f')$ is of positive degree and has at least one zero in $\mathbb F$.

Now use this theorem for $\mathbb F=\mathbb F_p$ and $f=x^p-a$ to deduce that $f$ has a multiple root.

*Note*. Actually you can prove that this special polynomial equals $(x-a)^p$.

Comment: by $g = (f,f')$ you mean the GCD? and well $x^p-a$ has positive degree . and has zero $a^p-a^p$, hence mulitple root

Comment: Yes I mean GCD...you should prove that GCD of polynomial and it's derivative is of positive degree and has at least one zero, which in this special case is obvious. This was your proof correction and the counter-example has been made in the above. So your proof is correct and only need to observe that the GCD has a root.